# Kettle to encrypt file using PGP

Tags: java, etl, kettle, user-defined

I want to encrypt files using PGP in Pentaho.
I have a Java program to encrypt the file through command line.
Kettle recommends to encrypt row by row using user defined call, Is there a way to encrypt whole file as such using kettle user defined class? I am new to kettle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about your requirement. but you can develop kettle plugin

http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2010/06/developing-a-custom-kettle-plugin-a-simple-transformation-step/

In the plugin just pass filename to method Runtime.exec() to encrypt your file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Create a new Kettle Job, add your file transformation to the flow job, now use the **Encrypt files with PGP Step**.

Comment: I tried that using gpg2.exe, but it says could not find public key even after importing the key.... Can you explain this part?

Comment: sorry i do not use windows os. i only use kettle on Linux

Comment: Hi... Can you explain how to use in Linux, the configuration I had to provide, we will be finally using this in a LINUX machine

Comment: Hi... Can you explain how to use in Linux, the configuration I had to provide, we will be finally using this in a LINUX machine

Comment: You can use GnuPG to generate a key. then use the kettle job to encrypt file within this key.  -> https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c14.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at job level. you have a step called Encrypt PGP files. This has to be used at job level. Hope I have answered your question.